# ConcurrentStack - Removing From Bottom Or Equivalent Functionality

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

I've been searching for a while for an answer to my question, but I have not found a good solution to my problem. 
What i'm trying to do is basically have a concurrent collection that is sort of like a ConcurrentStack but I need to be able to remove items from the bottom of the stack. This is because I wish to have the stack be only of a certain length, and thus any old items will get removed from the bottom when the collection gets too big.

The concurrent stack works great with the adding of objects, but removing them from the bottom is what I can't figure out.

I also had an idea of having a ConcurrentDictionary where I keep track of the date added, and the object stored, and then remove items based on the last date?

Any help/ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: you can do it in a way, you can use PopRange into another list then clear remaining items and then push back the popped items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [ConcurrentQueue Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)

Comment: It's unclear if he wants to *only* remove from the "bottom", in which case this is exactly what he should be doing, or if he really needs to remove from both ends, in which case what he really needs is a `ConcurrentDeque` (which doesn't exist).

Comment: Already looked at that. Not the functionality I want, as I want the newest item i added to be on top like the stack, and then gets pushed down by newer additions until its at the end and gets removed when there are X number of items in front of it. Think of a linked list where I want access to the head and tail at all times. Don't care about whats in between and long as its in the order they are added.

Comment: @Michaela If you're always removing the "oldest" item then you do indeed want a `ConcurrentQueue`.

Comment: Yes but again i'm missing access to the other side of the collection. If i add an item to the queue I want to be able to access that item as well as be able to remove the item at the other side.

Comment: After looking at ConcurrentQueue again, I ended up using it. In order to get the items that were added the most recently (at the end of the queue) I copied the queue to a list (thus taking a snapshot of what is currently in it) and took the last one.